# Cannot set dark app theme Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, themes

I was trying to set dark background in theme like this -

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background_material_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/abc_primary_text_material_dark</item>
</style>
```

It is working on Android Lollipop, Marshmallow and Nougat, but on KitKat and older systems, the background is white. Could someone help me? (I want to keep ActionBar too)

Comment: Just a tip, black is not today's best design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're using is `android:colorBackground`, to change the **Window Background** you must **also** add `android:windowBackground` to the same value.

[image]

Comment: Great, working, thanks! I couldn't guess how to set it

Comment: If you think my answer was useful, please consider up-voting it :)